Windsurf. Ошибка "Service under load, try again later." при запросе
Работаю в IDE Windsurf, все было хорошо, ИИ редактировал код, но в один день после отправки промпта задачи появилась ошибка "Service under load, try again later.".
В output выводится следующее: [Error - 9:56:49 PM] Stopping server failed
Message: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
Code: -32099
[Error - 9:56:49 PM] Stopping server failed
Message: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
Code: -32099
Посмотрел всю документацию, не понимаю, с чем это может быть связано

также возникла проблема с работой расширения Codeium как в редакторе Windsurf, так и в Visual Studio Code. Проблема появилась с вечера вчерашнего дня. Я пробовал решить её различными способами: -Использовал локальную машину и удалённый сервер,
-Очищал папки кэша,
-Пробовал разные учётные записи Codeium К сожалению, ни один из этих методов не помог.

Видимо они больше не работают в РФ или СНГ. Еще раз попробовал его воскресить и получил следующее сообщение "Feature not available in your country."

В моем случае использование cascade модель работает. ip использую Джакарта, Индонезия

Проблема действительно оказалось в том, что они ушли из России.
Решается установкой и запуском VPN.
